# SceneKit – App won't use SCNCamera upon launch

Tags: ios, scenekit, scnnode

Not sure if it my code or not or I'm just plain missing something. Upon my app launching its as if a default camera is used which is at world centre. If I double tap to screen it seems to jump to the camera I have created myself. My understanding is that the default camera is used only if there is no other camera in the scene. Question is how do I get my app to look through my custom camera on launch? Heres my camera function which is called in the init method of my class.

```
func addCameraNode() {

    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 50, 0)
    cameraNode.camera?.zNear = 0.1
    cameraNode.camera?.zFar = 200
    cameraNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(3.14, 0, 0)
    theScene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the point of view using SCNView's pointOfView property:

```
scnView.pointOfView = cameraNode;
```